# php in html files

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, movabletype

How do you configure movable type to allow php in html files? I have seen places that people do the php tag in a html file and the server knows how to interpret the php in the html file. Is there a way to do this for Movable Type?

Answer (score 4):

Have a read here: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Answer (score 1):

Movable Type can output anything. If you name a template with .php and then include php in your template, when the rendered file is browsed, it'll be interpreted as php.

Same goes for asp, jsp, css, html... as long as your web server can serve it, Movable Type can output it.

Answer (score 0):

Movable Type would publish the content exactly as you're writing it inside the movable type admin, in other words you don't need to do anything to movable type to interpret the php coding that you might place inside your pages.

If you have movable type configured to publishes pages with the .php extension, then the server would correctly implement your php coding.

But since you are having movable type configured to publish pages with the .html extension, those pages are interpreted by the server as HTML pages. What you need to do is to configure your server so that it will interpret your .html pages as PHP.

This setting could vary from a server to another, but you would usually add the following to your .htaccess file:

AddHandler php5-script .html

This change could also be done from inside Cpanel, under:
Advanced -> Apache Handlers

Check your site pages after implementing such a change and make sure that they work properly because it could generate errors and you may like to revert back the setting until you find the suitable one for your server environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php in html codes,but the file need to be in PHP,you can use HTML also,it doesn't matter that is PHP.For example this code is in HTML and also have PHP:

```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body class="page_bg">
   Hello, today is 
  <?php 
  echo "Hello world";
  ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

To conclude,the file must be in PHP.This don't mean a problem where you work in HTML,but for use PHP you need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

No, not really.

You can put HTML in a PHP file.  This works because the PHP interpreter recognizes the PHP parts (and processes them), and also recognizes the HTML parts (and passes them on directly).

With Movable Type, you typically don't have a PHP interpreter.

There's been discussion about porting Movable Type from Perl to PHP:

http://forums.movabletype.org/2008/09/full-php-movable-type-platform.html